# Remove 'blog' section in the Github Jekyll

Tags: github, post, repository, jekyll, blogs

I am wondering how to use the Github Jekyll website without the 'Blog' section (that includes posts). Could you share your solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have to make the assumption that you have a blog page, either `blog.html` or `blog/index.html`, and in that page you have a `for` loop calling `site.posts` or `paginator.posts`. You have two options:

1. Delete the `_posts` directory.
2. If you want to keep the posts in `_posts` but don't want them to display on your site, don't use those `for` loops mentioned above and you won't see the posts on the frontend.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I want the second option. How can I remove the for loops in the blog/index.html in Github?

Comment: Deleting them from the index.html file should work, no?